# How to list all files of a directory recursively in c

Tags: c, file, dirent.h

This is a c program that list all files of a directory recursively , so it can list all files in c: drive for example .

The above program works fine but i've been trying for 5 days and i can't get it to work without using a function (only main , not main and the other function (listFilesRecursively) )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>

void listFilesRecursively(char *path);


int main()
{
    // Directory path to list files
    char path[100];

    // Input path from user
    strcpy(path , "c://");

    listFilesRecursively(path);

    return 0;
}


/**
 * Lists all files and sub-directories recursively 
 * considering path as base path.
 */
void listFilesRecursively(char *basePath)
{
    char path[1000];
    struct dirent *dp;
    DIR *dir = opendir(basePath);

    // Unable to open directory stream
    if (!dir)
        return;

    while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(dp->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dp->d_name, "..") != 0)
        {
            printf("%s\n", dp->d_name);

            // Construct new path from our base path
            strcpy(path, basePath);
            strcat(path, "/");
            strcat(path, dp->d_name);

            listFilesRecursively(path);
        }
    }

    closedir(dir);
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: the `main()` functiion does not work 'recursively' so you need that 'sub function' that can call itself recursively

Comment: the code should be looking at the field: `unsigned char  d_type; ` to determine if the current entry is a directory or a symbolic link or a regular file.  the code should not make the assumption that every entry is for a sub directory.  Suggest reading [readdir info](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html)  Only want to 'reccurse' when `d_type` is `DT_DIR`

Comment: for a more robust method, suggest looking at the function: `nftw() [MAN nftw](https://linux.die.net/man/3/nftw)

Comment: @user3629249 also didn't find a way to put that in a code with only main()

Comment: My recollection is that `d_type` is not enormously portable, although I confess that I use it all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't for the life of me think why anybody would want to enumerate directories by calling `main()` recursively. But, since I can't resist a pointless challenge, here's a version that does. Do I get the prize for "most fruitless waste of ten minutes?" ;)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
  {
  const char *path;
  if (argc != 2) path = "/etc"; /* Set starting directory, if not passed */
  else
    path = argv[1];

  DIR *dir = opendir (path);
  if (dir)
    {
    struct dirent *dp;
    while ((dp = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
      {
      if (dp->d_name[0] != '.')
        {
        char *fullpath = malloc (strlen (path) + strlen (dp->d_name) + 2);
        strcpy (fullpath, path);
        strcat (fullpath, "/");
        strcat (fullpath, dp->d_name);
        if (dp->d_type == DT_DIR)
          {
          char **new_argv = malloc (2 * sizeof (char *));
          new_argv[0] = argv[0];
          new_argv[1] = fullpath;
          main (2, new_argv);
          free (new_argv);
          }
        else
          printf ("%s\n", fullpath);
        free (fullpath);
        }
      }
    closedir(dir);
    }
  else
    fprintf (stderr, "Can't open dir %s: %s", path, strerror (errno));
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: `char **new_argv = malloc (2 * sizeof (char *));` ==> `char *new_argv[3]; new_argv[0] = argv[0]; new_argv[1] = fullpath; new_argv[2] = NULL;` and remove `free (new_argv);`

Comment: @Andrew Henle  -- Yeah, fair point. I wasn't aiming for efficiency ;)

Comment: thanks , why did you do "char *fullpath = malloc (strlen (path) + strlen (dp->d_name) + 2);" instead of char *fullpath; ?

Comment: @random dude -- you have to allocate memory for the string. It needs to be large enough to take the original path, the separator, the new filename, and the terminating null. Alternatively, you could just say something like `char fullpath[PATH_MAX]`, and get a fixed-size memory block. I started programming in the days when the largest amount you could allocate that way was about 64 bytes, so I usually allocate the exact amount using `malloc`.

Comment: you said its not good why and which would you like more ?